# Protractor Firefox 45.0.1: How to bypass Security Warning

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, protractor

My chrome protractor tests go through but firefox 45.0.1 (coz the latest firefox is incompatible) throws a security warning popup as i navigate away from an https from page. Any one know a hack? Suggestions about changing the value of `security.warn` from `true` to `false` in `about:config` not working for me. That option (`security.warn`) is not there.

Comment: You might wanna try setting `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` to `true`. I'm not sure that is the setting that causes it but judging by the name I feel like it could be it.

Comment: @RemcoW not working unfort. Thanks